# Need to make work setText and getText more than once

Tags: android

I have been trying to build a calculator, like when i click Button "1", it will show "100" on text view but in the calculation it will get value "1". So as "200" when pressed button "2". I made separate gettext() and settext() when button clicked. When button is clicked for the first time it works fine. But nothing works when i press another button. E.g if i press button"1" and then "3" it should get value "13" and set text to "100300". But it doesn't do that.It only shows"100" when pressed button"1",no matter how many times i press button after first time.It stops setText() and getText() 
{1=১,2=২,3=৩,4=৪,5=৫,6=৬,7=৭,8=৮,9=৯}  Here's my code sample

```
public class MainActivity extends      AppCompatActivity implements                                                
 View.OnClickListener {
Button btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4,    btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9
char op;
TextView eresult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
typecast();
btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
btn9.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void typecast() {


eresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

}
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.zero) {
eresult.setText("000");
result.getText().equals(0);
}

else if (v.getId() == R.id.one) {
eresult.setText("100");
eresult.getText().equals(1);
} 
 else if (v.getId() == R.id.two) {
eresult.setText("200");
eresult.getText().equals(2);
} 
 else if (v.getId() == R.id.three) {
 eresult.setText("300");
eresult.getText().equals(3);
} 
else if (v.getId() == R.id.four) {
eresult.setText("400");
eresult.getText().equals(4);
} 
else if (v.getId() == R.id.five) {
eresult.setText("500");
eresult.getText().equals(5);
} 
else if (v.getId() == R.id.six) {
eresult.setText("600");
eresult.getText().equals(6);
} 
else if (v.getId() == R.id.seven) {
eresult.setText("700");
eresult.getText().equals(7);
} 
else if (v.getId() == R.id.eight) {
eresult.setText("800");
eresult.getText().equals(8);
}
else if (v.getId() == R.id.nine) {
eresult.setText("900");
eresult.getText().equals(9);
}
```

[image: screebshot when button "1" and then "3" pressed]

Answer (score 1):

It is only showing 100 and not 100300, because you are overwriting the text. For that you have to append the text to your textView. So, Every time while setting text, do following:

```
eresult.setText(eresult.getText().toString + "300");
```

First get the text from the textView and then append the new one. For each button you have to do this.

Edit: And to avoid nullPointer exception, check every time whether the textView is null or not. Basically:

```
if(eresult.getText()!=null){
    eresult.setText(eresult.getText().toString + "300");
}
```

Comment: doesn't that also get the value of 300 ?instead of 3.i just want to display "300" but the value remains "3". I am saying that because i am making calculator with my country language. Where value remains the same but it displays something else.